# Event to trigger related list data change

Tags: lightning, refresh

I see that there is a force:refereshview handler event that i can use to handle refreshview

The challenge is when the related list is edited the refreshview does not fire consistently(Observed this when editing/deleting individual account team member from account)

Is there a handler for capturing relatedlist changes in general instead of relying on refreshview event?